# Call to member function getClientOriginalExtension() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

try multiple file upload in Laravel so my code for view is

```
<input type="file" name="photos">
```

but i facing this problem to cant exact type .. ?

```
   $img = $request->file('photos');
  $fileExtension=$img->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/call-to-a-member-function-getclientoriginalextension-on-a-non-object) may help .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are posting single image. You try this code :-

```
if($request->hasFile('photos')){
if (Input::file('photos')->isValid()) {
    $file = Input::file('photos');
    $destination = 'images/Foldername'.'/';
    $ext= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $mainFilename = str_random(6).date('h-i-s');
    $file->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
    echo "uploaded successfully";
}
}
```

Make sure You have added the enctype in form:-

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="photos">
 </form>
```

If you are uploading multiple images. Try this code:-

```
if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
$files = $request->file('photos');
foreach($files as $file){
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = str_random(5)."-".date('his')."-".str_random(3).".".$extension;
    $destinationPath = 'images/Foldername'.'/';
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
}
```

And form must look like this :-

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
 </form>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In `$img` you got an array. And you shoud use loop like `foreach` to operate with `$img`