# Insert Multiple Rows in Laravel (Image Upload Issues)

Tags: laravel-8

In my application, I have faced several issues when I try to insert multiple rows of data into a database in laravel 8. Basically this issues is related to image upload. I have add related code to get help.

Controller View:

```
        foreach($request->param_img as $key => $param_img){
         $data = new PortfolioParam;
         $data->param_desc = $request->param_desc[$key];
   

    if($request->hasfile('param_img')){
        $file = $request->file('param_img');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('upload/portfolio_param/', $filename);
        $portfolio->param_img = $filename; 
    }

    $data->portfolio_id = $portfolio->id;
    $data->save();
}
```

Blade View:

```
<td class="pl-0 border-0">
 <textarea class="form-control" name="param_desc[]" id="" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
</td>
<td class="border-0">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="param_img[]">
</td>
```

Error

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array
```

How can I get rid of this problems??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to member function getClientOriginalExtension() in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537366/call-to-member-function-getclientoriginalextension-in-laravel)

Comment: No..  this haven't answer

Comment: Please explain - how did foreach not fix your issue here?

Comment: @Stoff please have a look on the controller view. There is a outer loop and inside the loop I have made an object of PortfolioParam. Then I store param_desc, and portfolio id. Which are perfectly saved.

But incase of img, it can;t save 

Please look on the blade view also

Comment: I see that. But you have not foreached your $file. And file is an array. Blade view has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Stoff can, you again see the controller view please. I have changed this. In this way how can I get desired result?

Need to say that, There is a js loop and a + button on the dashboad to add multiple rows.  Please have a look on this too->...... https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/34137209?key=5029bda576e024e899af729cb551d93c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have looped through the image but you have not used it in your image uploading code. You are still using the request data. Check this out, hopefully it helps.

```
    // $file = $request->file('param_img');
    $file = $param_img;
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
    $file->move('upload/portfolio_param/', $filename);
    $portfolio->param_img = $filename;
```